# Rewrite sum of functions as a union of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For each $n\in\Bbb Z$, let $f_n\colon [n,n+1]\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $f_{n}(n+1)=f_{n+1}(n+1)$ and $f_n$ is $0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus [n,n+1]$. Now, define $f$ as follows $$f=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} f_n$$ Clearly, $f$ is a function form $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R.$ My question is

> Can I think for $f$ as  $f=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} f_n.$?

I think they are the same. Is that right? Any idea.

Comment: How do you define the sum of functions of distinct domains? $\cup f_n$ is more natural to think of than $\Sigma f_n$ by treating functions as binary relations.

Comment: @Hermis14, thank you and I forgot to finish the definition of $f_n$

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
Let me rephrase your question.
Let $(f_n)_{n \in \Z}$ be the sequence of functions defined such that for each $n \in \Z$, $f_n: [n, n+1] \to \R$ and $f_n(n+1) = f_{n+1}(n+1)$ with a base case.
A function is a special case of binary relations: $f_n \subseteq [n, n+1] \times \R$, that is, each $f_n$ is a set. Therefore, it is natural to think of the union of those,
$$
f = \bigcup_{n \in \Z}f_n
$$
We can easily verify that the union is also a function because the function values of $f_n$ agree on each endpoint of the domains by definition; for all $n \in \Z$, there is unique $y \in \R$ such that $(n, y) \in f$, or equivalently, $y = f(n)$.

However, I've not seen anyone try summing functions of different domains unless it is defined specifically with a special purpose. This means, you need to tell us how to sum such functions.

Comment: The OP edited some time ago to add that $f_n=0$ on $\mathbb R-[n,n+1]$. So they have a common domain now.

Comment: I fixed before you sent your answer check now

Comment: @drhab Thanks for pointing it out, but the OP still states that $\textrm{dom}f_n = [n, n+1]$. How are the paired domains the same for each $n$? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I agree that the question is unclear on this. The OP speaks of functions $[n,n+1]\to\Bbb R$ (suggesting that $[n,n+1]$ serves as domain) but later (by means of an edit) says that these functions take value $0$ outside this interval (suggesting that $\Bbb R$ serves as common domain). He did that inspired by your comment on the question and I think you should go in your answer for the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be that for every $n\in\mathbb Z$ function $f_n$ only takes value $1$ on interval $[n,n+1]$.

Then e.g. $(3.5,1)\in f_3\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}f_n$.

But also $(3.5,0)\in f_7\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}f_n$.

This shows us that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}f_n$ is not (the graph of) a function.

Comment: drhab, $f(3.5)=1$ why $f$ is not function ?

Comment: I am not saying that $f$ is not a function but that the union of $f_n$'s is not a function (hence cannot equalize function $f$). If $(a,b), (a,c)\in g$ where $g$ is a function then $b=g(a)=c$. So it is not possible that the ordered pairs $(3.5,0)$ and $(3.5,1)$ are both elements of a function. Every input should have exactly one output.

Comment: Let me add that the union would be a function if every $f_n$ would have $[n,n+1]$ as domain. However in that case you meet another obstacle: you cannot take the summation of the $f_n$.

Comment: drhab,  in your first comment you said $f$ is as function but not equal to the union so it will equal to the sum. Right?

Comment: In your question $f$ is *defined* as sum $\sum_n f_n$. This sum is a function but the union is not a function. So they cannot coincide.

Comment: drhab, is there a way can we make the union and the sum coincide ?

Comment: No, I don't think we can.

Comment: drhab, $f^{-1} (U)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} f_n ^{-1} (U)$ where $U$ is an open set. Is that right?

Comment: No. If the functions $f_n$ are defined as in my answer then $f(1)=f_0(1)+f_1(1)=1+1=2$ so that $f^{-1}(U)\neq\varnothing$ for set $U=(1.5,3)$. This while $f_n^{-1}(U)=\varnothing$ for every $n$.

Comment: drhab. You are right and thank for your comments. I am trying to show if each $f_n ^{-1} (U)$ is $G_{\sigma\delta}$ then $f$ does so. This is why I was trying to rewrite as a union. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: That is another question. I haven't thought about that. Also I think you should stop here because going on with new subjects is not really where comments are for. The question that was posed has an answer and of course you can pose new questions about the subject. This eventually with a link to this question.